# toward/towards PhD degree

Tags: word-choice

I'm a little confused about using *toward* and *towards* in sentences. For a PhD student is it correct to say:

> He is moving toward PhD degree

or

> He is moving towards PhD degree

?

Should I use **the** before PhD in this sentence?

Comment: Ame prefers "toward" where BrE favours "towards", but both versions are in common use on both sides of the pond. Note that syntactically, your context *requires* a determiner before "PhD degree" - but idiomatically we simply wouldn't use "the" in the cited context (where "his", or "a" are far more natural). To be honest, I don't think much of "**moving** [toward/s]" either. I suspect you're just using flowery metaphoric language for the sake of it.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks, What is a good alternative for "moving" here?

Comment: @TypeIA has provided several perfectly good alternatives

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to say that a person is enrolled in a PhD program and trying to obtain a PhD degree? There are better ways to say this:

> - He is pursuing his/a PhD.
> - He is working toward(s)/on his/a PhD.
> - He is getting his/a PhD.

All of these variations are common, at least in American English, and have roughly the same meaning. The last version might imply a higher degree of certainty that he will actually complete the program and receive his PhD.

In any case, an article or pronoun is definitely required. A degree is an item (physical or notional) that is received by a person.

Comment: I'm writing a bio. Yes, I'm talking about a person who is a PhD student. I wanted to express this in other words (not using student or similar words). Thanks, but I didn't understand which one is correct! toward or towards?

Comment: @Pablo Both are acceptable. "Toward" is the preferred spelling in American English, while "towards" is favored (or favoured :)) in British English. There is some crossover.